# An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm getting this error in my cloudwatch logs

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I'm authorizing an IAM User with full admin access to my boto3.client DynamoDB table and it's giving me that error. Here's my application code for context

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, render_template, request
import requests
import boto3
import os

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

pages = Blueprint('pages', __name__)
app = Flask(__name__) 

table_name = "counterdb"
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name="us-west-2", aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
db_client = boto3.client("dynamodb", region_name="us-west-2", aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)


def increment_visitor():
    response = db_client.update_item(
        TableName=table_name,
        Key = {
            'Primary Key': {
                'N': "0"
            }
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues = { ":inc": {"N": "1"}},
        UpdateExpression = "ADD visitor :inc"
    )


def retrieve_visitor_count():
    item = table.get_item(
        Key = {
            "Primary Key": 0
        }
    )
    visitcount = (item["Item"])["visitor"]
    return visitcount


def handler():
    increment_visitor()
    return retrieve_visitor_count()

# @app.before_first_request
# def before_first_request():
#     dbcounter = handler()
#     print(dbcounter)
    
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    handler()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

I originally didn't have the region specified and was told that could be it, so I added a region as well. I got the same error with and without specifying the region in my boto3.client. I triple checked and it's the correct IAM User that I'm using with full admin access, do I need more permissions or is this a different issue causing the error?

Comment: Where is this running on?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I'm using ECS + Fargate, forgot to mention that in my post

Comment: And your **task** role has full admin access?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary my ecs task has the ecstaskdefinition role, should I create a new role with those privileges plus DynamoDB privileges?

Comment: I don’t recall that being a role name but regardless yes - try that

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I created a new role with full admin access and I was still getting those errors